# Проверка на наличие последовательности символов в textarea

Tags: php

На странице есть textarea, как правильно написать пробую проверить наличие в нём хоть каких-то символов этим условием:

```
if (!strlen($urlslist)= 0) {echo 666666666666666666666666666}
```

но выдаёт ошибку, где я не так делаю?

Comment: Может всё же `strlen($urlslist) != 0`?

Comment: сколько же нервных клеток было сожжено из-за это ошибки за всю историю программирования)))

Comment: неа, тоже не хочет работать

Comment: @Никола: что значит "не хочет работать"? (1) В переменной `$urlslist` непустая строка, но условие `strlen($urlslist) != 0` не выполняется? (2) условие выполняется, но в блок `echo 6666...` выполнение программы не заходит, (3) что-то ещё?

Comment: что за ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'string';
//$str = '';

if(strlen($str) ? true : false) echo $str; return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

`!strlen($urlslist)= 0` - это Вы че под этим хотите получить? `!strlen($urlslist)` вернет `boolean`, а вы потом присваиваете ему 0 условия, то никакого нет. Тогда уж наверно так

```
if( strlen($urlslist) > 0 ){
   echo '666666666666666666666666666666666';
}
```